# Is there a Perl plugin for IntelliJ?

Tags: perl, intellij-idea

What do people do when they want to write Perl in [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)? I haven't seen any plugins that add language support. Does anyone have any experience writing language plugins for IntelliJ?
Is it hard? Could I take an existing plugin and change it to make it support Perl? Any suggestions?

Comment: If someone starts doing one and needs some testing, let a comment here.

Comment: There is now a plugin for IntelliJ - https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA

Answer (score 20):

Currently I believe there is no Perl plugin for IntelliJ.

The IntelliJ website has [several tutorials](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/plugins/plugin_developers.html) on how to write plugins. They also have a special sections that is devoted to [developing language plugins](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/plugins/developing_custom_language_plugins.html).

I have no idea how hard it would be, but you would definitely learn a lot.

I would guess that modifying an existing plugin would probably just create a mess, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I have raised a feature request here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109346
Please vote for this if you would find it valuable.

Comment: A Perl plugin was created just recently: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796

Answer (score 5):

As per my comment above, I think it would be great if there was an IntelliJ plugin for Perl 5.

Please vote for this feature request here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=368 and here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109346 and we might get one.